# Understadint using getilne in specific example

Tags: c++, csv, vector, struct, getline

I know the question I'm going to ask could be a possible duplicate, but I was unable to solve the problem given the answers to similar questions. I just started using C++ and I'm not very familiar with it.

I have the following problem with the reading of an CSV file of 4 columns and almost 28000 rows. The problem relies in the fact that I can't understand the `std::getline()` function, which I thought I knew its behaviour until I printed the result.

The names of the variables are really related to the project, so I'm going to apologize if the code is not much readable, I decided to call `s_index` as "start index" and `e_index` as "end index", similarly `v_boolean` is a boolean vector, and the generical node of my struct called `NodeGraph` is a `Node` which represent a node (of integers) of a Public Transport oriented `Graph`, initialized with `vector`.

The code look like this:

```
// Reading network_walk.csv
cout << "Reading network_walk.csv" << endl;

ifstream thirdfile;
string thirdfile_line;

thirdfile.open("network_walk.csv");
getline(thirdfile,thirdfile_line); // Skip the first row

while(!thirdfile.eof()) {

    getline(thirdfile, thirdfile_line, ';');

    int s_index = atoi(thirdfile_line.c_str());

    getline(thirdfile, thirdfile_line, ';');
    int e_index = atoi(thirdfile_line.c_str());

    cout << s_index << " " << e_index << "" <<endl;

    if (v_boolean[s_index]*v_boolean[e_index] == true ) {

        NodeGraph Node;

        Node.to_stop_I = e_index;

        getline(thirdfile, thirdfile_line, ';');
        Node.arr_time = (atoi(thirdfile_line.c_str()))*36.0 /50.0;

        getline(thirdfile, thirdfile_line, ';'); //Ignore the third data.

        Node.route_type = -1;

        Graph[s_index].push_back(Node);

    }

    getline(thirdfile, thirdfile_line);
}

thirdfile.close();
```

What I should get and what I actually get are shown below:

[image]

[image]

Comment: It is not really clear what the actual problem is.  Please clarify. Also, what does the CSV file actually look like, and what are you expecting your output to look like from it?

Comment: I’d like to print the exact same rows of the csv file but it seems it’s skipping some rows instead

Comment: Again, what does the actual CSV file look like? How many columns does it have exactly? What is actually getting skipped? Please provide a simpler example.  Also, consider reading each line from the file into a `std::string` first, and then use a separate `std::istringstream` to parse out values from that `std::string` as needed.

Comment: I think the problem is clear the example are that the first row for example, which has to_stop_id = 6657 is skipped as you can see in the output that should represent the first $$n$$ rows

Comment: "*I think the problem is clear*" - of course you would, since you are the one asking the question.  But for other people who would want to help you, more details are needed. How do you expect anyone to help you when you have not provided a [mcve] to demonstrate the problem in action. So again, what does the CSV file actually look like?  Please provide the first handful of lines so we can actually see what you are working with, and what you are missing.

Comment: @RemyLebeau All the CSV file look like the screenshot I linked, there are 27559 lines of the same type of the first eight you see, that's the reason why I did not link more.

Comment: I have posted an answer for you

Answer (score 1):

You have not shown the raw CSV file data, but your code depends on the 4th column being terminated by `;` before EOL. Your screenshots do not show if that is actually the case, but if the 4th column IS NOT terminated by `;` then [I can reproduce the issue](https://ideone.com/ZZl5ct) when your `v_boolean[]` elements evaluate to true.  Reading of the 4th column value will read past the EOL into the 1st column of the next line, and then the final `getline()` will skip the remainder of that next line, so you skip reading of the 2nd-4th columns of that line.  On the other hand, when the `v_boolean` elements evaluate to false, you skip the reading of the 3rd and 4th columns, and the final `getline()` reads until EOL of the current line, as expected.

When you specify a terminator *other than* `'\n'`, `std::getline()` WILL NOT stop reading on EOL, as expected.

The solution is to use `std::getline()` to read whole lines at a time, and then use `std::istringstream` to parse values from each line as needed.  Then it won't matter if the 4th column is terminated by `;` or not.

Try this instead:

```cpp
// Reading network_walk.csv
cout << "Reading network_walk.csv" << endl;

ifstream thirdfile;
string thirdfile_line;

thirdfile.open("network_walk.csv");
getline(thirdfile, thirdfile_line); // Skip the first row

while (getline(thirdfile, thirdfile_line)) {

    istringstream iss(thirdfile_line);
    string thirdfile_value;

    getline(iss, thirdfile_value, ';');
    int s_index = atoi(thirdfile_value.c_str());

    getline(iss, thirdfile_value, ';');
    int e_index = atoi(thirdfile_value.c_str());

    cout << s_index << " " << e_index << "" <<endl;

    if (v_boolean[s_index]*v_boolean[e_index]) {

        NodeGraph Node;

        Node.to_stop_I = e_index;

        getline(iss, thirdfile_value, ';');
        Node.arr_time = (atoi(thirdfile_value.c_str()))*36.0 /50.0;

        Node.route_type = -1;

        Graph[s_index].push_back(Node);
    }
}

thirdfile.close();
```

Alternatively, consider using `operator>>` instead of `getline()` to read the individual integers, eg:

```cpp
// Reading network_walk.csv
cout << "Reading network_walk.csv" << endl;

ifstream thirdfile;
string thirdfile_line;

thirdfile.open("network_walk.csv");
getline(thirdfile, thirdfile_line); // Skip the first row

while (getline(thirdfile, thirdfile_line)) {

    istringstream iss(thirdfile_line);
    int s_index, e_index;

    iss >> s_index;
    iss.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), ';');

    iss >> e_index;
    iss.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), ';');

    cout << s_index << " " << e_index << "" <<endl;

    if (v_boolean[s_index]*v_boolean[e_index]) {

        NodeGraph Node;

        Node.to_stop_I = e_index;

        int temp;
        iss >> temp;
        Node.arr_time = temp * 36.0 / 50.0;

        Node.route_type = -1;

        Graph[s_index].push_back(Node);
    }
}

thirdfile.close();
```